# Changing Element Attributes Based on a Condition

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to determine which attribute to render on an element? For example, say I wanted to style a div to have a green background if my `count` variable is greater than 5, but give it a ui-view directive otherwise?

Let's take an unrealistic example written in pseudocode

```
<div ng-if="count > 5 ? {style='background: green'} : {ui-view='home'}">

</div>
```

Is this plausible? I may be approaching it the wrong way but I wanted to know if this could or should be done (I'm thinking custom directives could help but I wanted to keep this as lightweight as possible)

Any help or discussion is appreciated!

Comment: ng-class / ng-style. see my udpated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
<div ng-if="myCondition"></div>
<div ng-if="!myCondition" ui-view></div>
```

In order to avoid code duplication I suggest to use ng-include:

```
<ng-include src="template"></ng-include>
```

Comment: this will work but more complicated, imagine in the content of the div is a big html, you have to duplicate code . ng-class / ng-style is adapted for his case

Comment: This does exactly what I want in just two lines! Thank you very much

Comment: you cannot set style with ng-if. ng-if is used to add or not a html part to the dom

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, ng-class is made for that

```
<div ng-class="{{ 'green' : (count > 5) ; 'red' : (count != 5) }}">

</div>
 // where green and red is class name not style
```

You can also use a variable for the class name

```
<div class="base-class" ng-class="myVar">Sample Text</div>
```

---

or ng-style 
 http://plnkr.co/edit/pCplLBymY1nmX7Bmb0uO?p=preview

```
  <span ng-style=" count > 5 ? { 'background-color':'red' } : { 'background-color':'green' }" >Sample Text</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't totally clear - I'm not looking to style a single attribute, but to swap attributes of the element completely based on a condition.
Updated the question